# Ejabberd: How to decouple Mnesia from the application server and use Mongodb plugin instead .. and how to handle big file transfers

Tags: mongodb, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

We are building a chatting application that should be able to handle millions of users, and capable of handling huge file transfers with ease; and we decided to use Ejabberd.

**So my question comes in 2 parts:**

**`Part One:`**

I did some research about replacing Mnesia db (which is RDMS db type) with Mongodb (NoSQL, where comes speed and scalability), which turns out to be not so efficient, as we will have to wrap the NoSQL interface as an RDBMS database.

I'm thinking of this approach: to disable the Mnesia database (the built-in db) of the Ejabberd server, and use mongodb-erlang plugin to store everything on, is that possible? And if possible is it efficient?

**`Part Two:`**

Is it the right way to handle the file transfers through Ejabberd's `mod_proxy65` plugin for such intended big files (users can pass videos) for millions of users, or there is a better approach, for example, to decouple the file transfer on a different application/proxy, I need some clarification on that part as well.

Comment: I'd recommend you split your question in two. They are not really tied to each other. 1 is about Mnesia/MongoDB and is wrong anyway (Mnesia is NOT rdbms in the traditional sense and you can't beat it with MongoDB for what it is built for). 2. is more about how to handle large data transfers in XMPP.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS, Mongodb is just an exmpale of NoSQL databases, I'm asking about the possibility of this setup in the first part of the question... So please answer my question if you know.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS, regarding the second part of your comment, my question is about Ejabberd's ability to handle this not if this is possible or not in XMPP